# Having trouble counting datetime objects that occur on same day, but one later

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I am looping through pairs of `datetime` objects and trying to count the pairs for which `d1` and `d2` occur on the same day, but `d2` occurs after `d1`.

The `if` statement:

```
if d1<= d2 and d1.date()==d2.date():
    count = count+1
```

Doesn't seem to be doing what I want.

Is this wrong?

Comment: Your statement looks correct. Can you give more context?

Comment: your logic is correct, however `d2` can occur at same time as `d1` by your logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test will correctly return `True` if `d1` and `d2` are equal or represent the same date, but `d1` is earlier in on that date than `d2`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> d1 = datetime.now()
>>> d2 = d1 + timedelta(minutes=20)  # slightly later
>>> d1 <= d2
True
>>> d1.date() == d2.date()
True
>>> d1 <= d2 and d1.date() == d2.date()
True
>>> d2 = d1 + timedelta(days=2)  # days later
>>> d1 <= d2 and d1.date() == d2.date()
False
>>> d2 = d1 - timedelta(minutes=20)  # slightly earlier
>>> d1 <= d2 and d1.date() == d2.date()
False
```

In other words, something *else* is wrong.